# Assigning score to raster based on cell overlap with other raster and field value

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a set of rasters that I've assigned scores to individually (scored based predominantly on values of other fields). The scoring scale is the same for all rasters, but the factors that determine score value differ for each raster.

I'm trying to figure out the best method for assigning a score to one of the rasters, call it raster1.

If field1 (an attribute of raster 1) is < 70 and raster1 overlaps with raster2, then assign value x to raster1.

I'm not trying to make a new raster, I just want to identify cells of raster1 that overlap with raster2 and assign those cells a value, assuming they also meet the other parameter (above). Doing a raster overlay addition would identify overlapping cells, but I'm not sure how I would use that as an identifier effectively.

Comment: Do you have spatial analyst? CON may be your friend here; it is almost inevitable to create a new raster (most tools do) which you can then MOSAIC back into your raster when the process is complete. Is value x a constant or derived from the raster?

Comment: I do have spatial analyst and x is derived from the raster. How exactly would the mosaic play in? I.e. how would creating a mosaic enable me to assign the score to raster1?

Comment: Mosaic (not mosaic to new raster) will enforce values of the results into the existing raster where non-null.

Comment: Ok. Nothing is null, but there are 0's. Will that matter? New to this approach.

Comment: as far as Mosaic is concerned there is data and nodata. You can do CON(Raster != 0,Raster) or setNull(Raster,0) which will create a raster where 0 is null suitable for mosaicing. Where your raster is data it will overwrite existing values, where your raster is nodata it will not overwrite.

Comment: I'd do mosaic all rasters to one (BIG). Calculate int(BIG-BIG). For each raster Con( IsNull("raster1"),BIG, 1), Con( IsNull("raster2"),BIG, 2), Con( IsNull("raster3"),BIG, 4). Find total of all CONs, this will give you, unique combination of overlaps, i.e. 5 - is area where 1st and 3rd overlaps. The rest is easy I assume?

Comment: Is there a way to just use the sql calculator in Con to achieve the null/non-null result? Also, if I do create a mosaic from the resulting raster, I'm still not sure how it will serve my original purpose. I want to populate raster1's attribute table with a score, not just visually see where it overlaps with raster2. Am I missing something?